# Go to eq item in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-plugins, scrollto

I have this script:

```
$('.blog-list li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').scrollTo('.section:eq(1)', 800);
});
```

When you click on the list item, you going now to `section:eq(1)`. I want change this script. When you click on the first list item, you going to the first section.

When you press the second list item. You're going to the second section etc. How can i make that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.blog-list li').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('body').scrollTo('.section:eq(' + $('.blog-list li').index(this) + ')', 800);
});
```

Comment: @Johan: That'll probably do in this case. I usually like to type it the other way around so that I'm specific about the collection the index is based on. ([For instance if `.blog-list` happens to be more than one list](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2cFt/))

Comment: As long as you know the side effects (like in your example), I guess it comes down to coding preferences. Just wanted to point it out :)

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/euBUh/)**

Use this code:

```
$('.blog-list li').each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $('body').scrollTo('.section:eq(' + i + ')', 800);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my vision of situation

```
 $('.bloc-list li').each(function(index,element){
        $(element).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').scrollTo('.section:eq(' + index + ')', 800);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.blog-list li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').scrollTo('.section:eq('+$(this).index()+')', 800);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xBEu5/1/)**

This method works by dynamically replacing the call to `:eq` with the index of the item that called the function, in this case, your list item by using `$(this).index()`.